# WPF NotifyIcon Balloon not showing up

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon, balloon-tip

Okay guys, quite new to C# but I'm getting on with it just fine.

I've got an application minimised to the system tray and I'm using [WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon) to do this. I'm trying to use the built in bubble tip feature.

Whilst I've got no errors, it just doesn't seem to be working.

My code is as follows:

```
    private void OnTaskBarMenuItemExitClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_isExplicitClose = true;//Set this to unclock the Minimize on close 

        this.Close();

        string title = "WPF NotifyIcon";
        string text = "This is a standard balloon";

        TaskBar.ShowBalloonTip(title, text, Properties.Resources.Server);
    }
```

What should happen is that when I close the application, it hides to the system tray (and does) but should also popup the BalloonTip (and doesn't).

Any ideas; I'm stumped? :(

Comment: Try using `Hide()` instead of `Close()`

Comment: This.Close() prevents it form trickering

Comment: It has nothing to do with the hide/close function - the balloon doesn't work in other functions either.

Comment: Can you please post more code then

Comment: Of what? This is the only issue???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some constraints on icon format and having done a TeamViewer session with the poster, we've come to the conclusion that it was the icon causing the issue.

```
private void OnTaskBarMenuItemExitClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_isExplicitClose = true;//Set this to unclock the Minimize on close 

    this.Close();

    string title = "WPF NotifyIcon";
    string text = "This is a standard balloon";

    TaskBar.ShowBalloonTip(title, text, BalloonIcon.Error);
}
```

Worked correctly and resolved the issue of the balloon not appearing.

Comment: So much yes oh my god.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnTaskBarMenuItemExitClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_isExplicitClose = true;//Set this to unclock the Minimize on close 

    this.Hide();

    string title = "WPF NotifyIcon";
    string text = "This is a standard balloon";

    TaskBar.ShowBalloonTip(title, text, Properties.Resources.Server);
}
```

check out this link: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Hiding_and_Showing_Forms_in_C_Sharp

Comment: It has nothing to do with the hide/close function - the balloon doesn't work in other functions either.

Comment: It sounds like you better use BeginInvoke() so just start another thread for this special case.

Comment: @deafjeff Your comment is not clear at all. Call `BeginInvoke` on what? If it was a UI element a new thread obviously wouldn't be used.